# How to Set a Javascript Object Key to Be Another Object's Value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an Javascript object called `person` with various properties such as `id`, `name`, `phone`, etc.

I want to create a new Javascript object called roster that is just the name. Something like this:

```
let person = { name: "Hilda", "id": 123, "phone": 000-000-0000 };
let roster = { person.name : person.phone };
```

However, React throws an error having `person.name` in the key. It doesn't matter if I do `person.name` or `person["name"]`. I have to do:

```
let roster = {};
roster[person.name] = person.phone;
```

Is there some special syntax to allow `person.name` to be set as the key directly, or is the work-around required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use []

```js
let person = { name: "Hilda", "id": 123, "phone": "000-000-0000" };
let roster = { [person.name] : person.phone };

console.log(roster)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've not seen array brackets used that way before. What is their syntactical significance?

Comment: Hi @Elliptica, I agree it feels a bit odd, but the idea is that's how you read the value `Object[key]`, so that's how you set the key as well `{ [computedKey] : "abc"}`. This is called a computed property name

Answer (score 1):

Vugar's answer is correct, this can be done by placing brackets `[]` around the first object's property name.

This is called a **computed property name**. From the MDN web docs:

> The object initializer syntax also supports computed property names.
> That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be
> computed and used as the property name. This is reminiscent of the
> bracket notation of the property accessor syntax, which you may have
> used to read and set properties already.
>
> Now you can use a similar syntax in object literals, too:

```
// Computed property names
let i = 0;
const a = {
  [`foo${++i}`]: i,
  [`foo${++i}`]: i,
  [`foo${++i}`]: i,
};

console.log(a.foo1); // 1
console.log(a.foo2); // 2
console.log(a.foo3); // 3

const items = ["A", "B", "C"];
const obj = {
  [items]: "Hello",
};
console.log(obj); // A,B,C: "Hello"
console.log(obj["A,B,C"]); // "Hello"

const param = 'size';
const config = {
  [param]: 12,
  [`mobile${param.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${param.slice(1)}`]: 4,
};

console.log(config); // {size: 12, mobileSize: 4}
```

[MDN Docs Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)